# Change the value of a mutable stack variable from inside an impl function?

Tags: testing, rust

This seems so incredibly simple. I expect a duplicate for this, but I have searched.

I'm trying to do a test that calling a method of a framework results in a method `parse` being called on all the `TextDocument`-implementing objects in a `HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>>` belonging to that framework. `TextDocument` is a trait.

So hopefully this enables me to implement a simple mock setup like this:

```
#[test]
fn each_text_document_is_parsed_in_framework_create_index() -> Result<()>{
    let mut docs_parsed = 0;
    let increment_count = ||{
        docs_parsed += 1
    };
    struct MockTextDocument {
        pub framework: Weak<Framework>,
    }
    impl TextDocument for MockTextDocument {
        fn parse(&self) -> Result<()> {
            increment_count();
            Ok(())
        }
    }
```

... then I call the method of the framework which is intended to cause this parsing, and finally do the test:

```
    framework.create_index();
    assert_eq!(docs_parsed, 3);
```

But this doesn't work. I get this from the compiler:

```
   Compiling populate_index_module v0.1.0 (D:\My documents\software projects\workspace\doc_indexer\src\core\populate_index_module)
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
   --> tests\test_1.rs:158:4
    |
158 |             increment_count();
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead
```

I was obviously trying to use a closure here. But clearly this is not the right way.

By the way, I can't use a property (such as `parsed: bool`) which might belong to `MockTextDocument` because the framework, for unavoidable reasons, is an `Rc<Framework>`, so all the `Box<dyn TextDocument>` values in the map are "behind shared references" and can't be accessed ... in other words I believe I have instead to use an external counter variable.

An added complication in my particular case is that a `MockTextDocument` can't just be created on the fly: it can only be created inside a function (which itself is a parameter of `Framework::new`). However, am following up what Vallentin says...

And in fact I don't think this is possible... so I think I'll have to cobble together another less elegant approach, like `parse` in the mock object prints "parse ..." to `stdout`, the contents of which I can then monitor.

**More details** (for ChayimFriedman)
This is how the mock documents are created, during the creation of the `Framework` in the test:

```
fn gather_mock_documents(walker: WalkDir, this: &Weak<Framework>) -> HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>> {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>> = HashMap::new();
    for i in 0..3 {
        let mock_td = MockTextDocument {
            framework: this.clone(),

            // it seems to me that any closure used here would 
            // have the same problem: no access to the stack variable
        };
        map.insert(format!("mock_doc_{i}"), Box::new(mock_td));
    }
    map
}

let framework = Framework::new("any_dir", String::from("dummy"), 
    &gather_mock_documents);
```

`Framework::new` is like this:

```
pub fn new(document_root_path: &str, index_name: String, 
    gather_closure: &dyn Fn(WalkDir, &Weak<Framework>) ->
        HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>>) -> Rc<Self> {
    let walker = WalkDir::new(document_root_path);
    let hf = Rc::new_cyclic(|this: &std::rc::Weak<Framework>|
        Framework{ 
            index_name,
            root_documents_path_str: String::from(document_root_path),  
            text_doc_map: gather_closure(walker, this),
        }
    );
    hf
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `increment_count` to either `MockTextDocument` or `parse()`. Just because you place a `struct` or `impl` within a function, that doesn't suddenly make it capture variables. It acts exactly the same way, as if you'd put the `struct` and `impl` outside of `each_text_document_is_parsed_in_framework_create_index`

Comment: "can't capture dynamic environment in a `fn` item" `parse` is a `fn` item `increment_count` is dynamic.

Comment: @vallentin got it... working on that ...

Comment: Why can't you add `increment()` as a field of `MockTextDocument`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Because the `MockTextDocument`s are created inside a function (so can't access the stack variable either). That relates to the last question I asked, which you answered. I'm going to show the problem as to how I'm creating mocks in the `Framework` (which in the non-mock implementation follows your solution using `Rc::new_cyclic`). Perhaps you can think of something...

Comment: If you cannot do anything else, you still have a better path than printing to stdout: stdout is a global resource, and you can as well have a global storing `increment`. Make it a thread local, so it doesn't interfere with other concurrently running tests.

Comment: @mikerodent Why wouldn't you be able to do [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f711ec041569feaf785440aab1cd2991)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That sounds good, will research.

Comment: Can't you add `increment` as a parameter to `gather_mock_documents()`?

Comment: @vallentin That looks incredibly clever.  But for the fact that `MockTextDocument` is created inside a function (as illustrated), so I think it'd come up against the same problem.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The trouble with that idea is that it would arbitrarily alter the signature of `gather_mock_documents` for the sake of testing, which is not desirable, right?

Comment: I thought (from the name) that it is a test-only function.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's the name in the test ... but it has the same signature as the (closure) parameter in `Framework::new`, as shown. In the application class that closure, as might be surmised, "walks" through the directory structure, gathering files and making (real) `TextDocument`s.

Comment: And the signature has to match? Why? Are you passing this function to some shared function? Perhaps you can make it a closure that will capture `increment`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ok, no doubt more naivety on my part. So the signature doesn't have to match? I'm going to look into that. If you care to add an answer showing the way ...

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge about your code, so I can't show how.

Comment: I've now shown the whole of `Framework::new` ... I tried changing the signature of the parameters of the expected `gather_closure` parameter ... but this resulted in errors. Are you saying that somehow it might be possible to stipulate `Framework::new`'s `gather_closure` parameter in a more generic way? I'm puzzled. (Maybe we should move to chat if you have time to say more?)

Comment: I see you are passing closure to `new()`, so you can just make `gather_mock_documents()` a closure that captures `increment`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257182/discussion-between-chayim-friedman-and-mike-rodent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... thanks to Chayim Friedman's suggestions.

```
struct MockTextDocument {
    pub framework: Weak<Framework>,
    parse_count: Rc<RefCell<i32>>,
}

impl TextDocument for MockTextDocument {
    fn get_framework(&self) -> &Weak<Framework>{
        &self.framework
    }

    fn parse(&self) -> Result<()> {
        *self.parse_count.borrow_mut() += 1;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[test]
fn each_text_document_is_parsed_in_framework_create_index() -> Result<()>{
    let parse_count = Rc::new(RefCell::new(0));
    let gather_mock_documents = |_: WalkDir, this: &Weak<Framework>| 
        -> HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>> {
        let mut map: HashMap<String, Box<dyn TextDocument>> = HashMap::new();
        for i in 0..3 {
            let mock_td = MockTextDocument {
                framework: this.clone(),
                parse_count: parse_count.clone(),
            };
            map.insert(format!("mock_doc_{i}"), Box::new(mock_td));
        }
        map
    };

    let framework = Framework::new("any_dir", String::from("dummy"), 
        &gather_mock_documents);

    let _ = framework.create_index();
    assert_eq!(*parse_count.borrow(), 3);
    
    Ok(())      
}
```